# How to parse JSON Array inside another JSON Array in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, web-services

Please, please help me..
I am working on a project and I am getting data from web-services in JSON format. I am trying to parse it but, I am unable to do it. I have this json-data-

```
 {
        "response": {
            "status": {
                "code": "1",
                "message": "sucess",
                "user_id": "1"
            },
            "foods": [
                {
                    "char": "A",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "food_name": "add Malt"
                        },
                        {
                            "food_name": "a la mode"
                        },
                        {
                            "food_name": "Almonds"
                        }
                 ]
            },
            {
                "char": "Z",
                "content": [
                    {
                        "food_name": "Zebra Cakes"
                    },
                        {
                            "food_name": "Zucchini, Baby"
                        },
                        {
                            "food_name": "zxc"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

From here I am successfully able to get "foods" Array but I am getting stuck when I am trying to get "content" array and food_name data.

I am using this code but I did not get any solution, please check this snip code.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method","eat_tracking_details"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid",userid));
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.urlname,"GET", nameValuePairs);
                //System.out.println("****json*"+json);
                if (json != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject response = json.getJSONObject("response");
                        JSONObject status = response.getJSONObject("status");
                        code = status.getString("code");
                        JSONArray FoodArray = response.getJSONArray("foods");
                        for (int i = 0; i < FoodArray.length(); i++) {
                            String character = FoodArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("char");
                            System.out.println("*****character****************"+character);
                            JSONArray FoodNameArray = new JSONArray(FoodArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("content"));
                            System.out.println("====================///////////"+FoodNameArray);

                            for (int j = 0; j <FoodNameArray.length(); j++) {
                                String Foodname = FoodArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("food_name");
                                System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+Foodname);
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
```

Check this url for web-service response-
[WEB-SERVICE URL](http://24x7serverhost.com/carenet/webservices/ws.php?method=eat_tracking_details&uid=1625)

Comment: You don't have to instantiate a new JSONArray, simply get it as you did for the foods array with the getJSONArray().

Comment: array is not in correct format and see this 

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: @fasteque you mean i should do like_JSONArray FoodArray = response.getJSONArray("content");?

Comment: @Rohit have you check given below link? Please use jsonlint array is ok no issue in array.

Comment: @DharaShah in case of gson I don't have to do manual parsing? do you have any demo please?

Comment: @ManishSrivastava yes you dont have to do manual parsing, just ensure that the entities are well defined. have a look at http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/ for an example, or mkyong's site also : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/, and this if it helps http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: JSONArray FoodNameArray = FoodArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("content");

Comment: @fasteque I have already tried that but its give me only first char "A" and related data.

Comment: Guys please give up vote to my question, so I can get correct answer, its very urgent.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *replace your **respective part** of code with this code*:

```
for (int j = 0; j < FoodNameArray.length(); j++) {
    String Foodname = FoodNameArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("food_name");
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + Foodname);
}
```

Comment: yes dear you are right, its working... very silly mistake :)
Thanks!

Comment: Then plz accept it as the correct answer so that other users can also benefit from it

Comment: Yes sure! and please if it is possible give one up-vote to my question .

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best approach would use of GSON library (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) . In that case you just have to make your model classes and don't worry about the parsing logic.

Comment: Dear can you check please that URL? and parse with out gson library. 
Everything okay just i am doing any silly mistake only.