# Json array inside array retrieve values Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

i m trying to get values from `JSONArray` inside array, i m able to retrieve whole JSON values into `JSONArray` successfully but  not able to retrieve values inside `JSONArray`. When i convert `JSONArray` to `JSONObject` to get values stored inside `JSONArray`. It gives error: `org.json.JSONException: No value for "banner"`

Here is JSON code, i verified JSON code with [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) and it showed JSON is Validate,

```js
[
 {"code":"banner","moduletitle":0,
   "banner":
  [
   {"image":"http://imageurl"},
   {"image":"http://imageurl"},
   {"image":"http://imageurl"}
  ]
  
 }
]
```

I m trying to get this from 3 hour but no luck. i m new in JSON and do not know how JSON Actually work, and also read abut **GSON Library** to get JSON values. here is My Java code.

```js
  JSONArray jsonObj = null;
            String image_url = "";
            String banner_code ="";

            try {
                jsonObj =new JSONArray(lib_function.getJSONUrl( jsontags.Top_Banner_JOSN_URLs));
                Log.d("value retrun :","" +jsonObj);
              //---vlaue is coming and print in Log ----// 
              
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.v("Error in Parser :", " " + e);
                Log.d("no value retrun :", "failed to convert");
            }

            try{
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
                    // populate the array
                    jo.put("arrayName", jsonObj);


                JSONArray subArray = jo.getJSONArray("banner");
                image_url= subArray.getString(Integer.parseInt("image"));


                Log.d("banner code",""+subArray);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("not working",""+e);
            }
```

I folllow this question but luck:
[How to parse JSON Array inside another JSON Array in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375374/how-to-parse-json-array-inside-another-json-array-in-android)

If anyone suggest, what i m doing wrong will be appreciate. or let me know, where i can get more information about json

**UPDATE** thanks too all to give their precious time for  answering my stupid question. All answers are correct , but i can accept only one answer.  A Big thanks to all

Comment: I the JSONArray create another JSONObject and get the value with specifying key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
// populate the array
jo.put("arrayName", jsonObj);
```

Because parsing `jsonObj` `JSONArray` so no need to create new `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` to extract it from `jsonObj`. remove all above three lines.

`banner` `JSONArray` is inside `JSONObject` which is contained by `jsonObj` `JSONArray`, get it as:

```
   JSONObject jsonObject=jsonObj.optJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray subArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("banner");

   // get code key from `jsonObject`
   String strCode=jsonObject.optString("code");

   // get all images urls from `subArray`
    for(int index=0;index<subArray.length();index++){
      JSONObject imgJSONObject=subArray.optJSONObject(index);
      // get image urls
      String strImgURL=imgJSONObject.optString("image");

     }
```

Also, if `jsonObj` JSONArray contains multiple JSONObject's then use `for-loop` to iterate it.

Comment: `jsonObj` is such a misleading name. This should be renamed to `jsonArray` for readability reasons :) +1 for your concise answer

Comment: what about **code** and  **image inside banner**  how can i get values of theme ?@ρяσѕρєя K

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have the rest of the values accessible to you, so posting just this snippet.

        `code=jsonObject.getString("code");
        moduletitle=jsonObject.getString("moduletitle");
        banner=jsonObject.getJSONArray("banner");`

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonObj =new JSONArray(lib_function.getJSONUrl( jsontags.Top_Banner_JOSN_URLs);
```

From above line you will get JSONArray. So now loop it and get you banner JSONArray.Again loop bannerArray and you will get image Urls

Answer (score 1):

If You want value of "image" which is in json arrray than

```
String response = "your response";
try{
    JsonArray jAry = new JsonArray(response);
    JsonObject jObj = jAry.getJsonObject(0);

    JsonArray jsonBanner = jObj.getJsonArray("banner");
    JsonObject temp;
    for(int i=0;i<jsonBanner.length;i++){
        temp = jsonBanner.getJsonObject(i);
        String image = temp.optString("image");
    }
}
```