# How to retrieve data from arrays inside arrays

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I'm trying to retrieve the html_instructions from this [json](/questions/tagged/json) the problem is that html_instructions is inside the array "steps" which is inside the array "legs" which is inside the array "routes", how do I get the "html_instructions"

Some part of the Json:

```
{
  geocoded_waypoints: [],
  routes: [
    {
      bounds: {
        northeast: {
          lat: 39.4798194,
          lng: -8.529889899999999
        },
        southwest: {
          lat: 39.2591911,
          lng: -8.7332564
        }
      },
      copyrights: "Dados do mapa ©2017 Google, Inst. Geogr. Nacional",
      legs: [
        {
          distance: {
            text: "44,6 km",
            value: 44551
          },
          duration: {
            text: "30 min.",
            value: 1818
          },
          end_address: "Torres Novas, Portugal",
          end_location: {
            lat: 39.47908200000001,
            lng: -8.5401204
          },
          start_address: "Santarém, Portugal",
          start_location: {
            lat: 39.2846595,
            lng: -8.7049071
          },
          steps: [
            {
              distance: {
              text: "0,3 km",
              value: 342
            },
          duration: {
            text: "1 min.",
            value: 60
          },
          end_location: {
            lat: 39.2822117,
            lng: -8.7036403
          },
          html_instructions: "Siga <b>sul</b> em direção a <b>N3</b>",
          polyline: {
            points: "cxwnFtdct@JEVGLCR?PDTFNHTNNNPJPDRDN?JCHCv@i@VQTK`CkF"
          },
          start_location: {
            lat: 39.2846595,
            lng: -8.7049071
          },
          travel_mode: "DRIVING"
        },
        {
          distance: {
            text: "0,6 km",
            value: 605
          },
          duration: {
            text: "1 min.",
            value: 66
          },
          end_location: {
            lat: 39.2772762,
          lng: -8.7058033
          },
          html_instructions: "Vire <b>à direita</b> em direção a <b>N3</b>",
          maneuver: "turn-right",
          polyline: {
            points: "yhwnFv|bt@NFx@XZL\RTNt@h@~C`CpAbAh@b@d@\h@^LJLHHBLDb@JP?JALAJAXCNCDANCLCLCPC`@Gz@KV@F@D@JDND"
          },
          start_location: {
            lat: 39.2822117,
            lng: -8.7036403
          },
        travel_mode: "DRIVING"
      },
```

This is what I have from java, which is not working:

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    //JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONArray routes = jsonObject.optJSONArray("routes");
                    if (routes != null) {
                        JSONArray legs = jsonObject.optJSONArray("legs");
                        if (legs != null){
                            JSONArray direcoes = jsonObject.optJSONArray("steps");
                            if (direcoes != null) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < direcoes.length(); j++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = direcoes.getJSONObject(j);

                                    String Distancia = jsonObject1.getString("distance");
                                    String Duracao = jsonObject1.getString("duration");
                                    String Instrucoes = jsonObject1.getString("html_instructions");


                                    HashMap<String, String> direcao = new HashMap<>();

                                    direcao.put("distance", Distancia);
                                    direcao.put("duration", Duracao);
                                    direcao.put("html_instructions", Instrucoes);

                                    listaDirecoes.add(direcao);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }



                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060525/json-array-inside-array-retrieve-values-android. Check this link

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < stepsArray.size; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = stepsArray.get(i);
            JSONObject directionObject = jsonObject.get("distance");
            JSONObject durationObject = jsonObject.get("duration");
            JSONObject end_loc = jsonObject.get("end_location");
            String html = jsonObject.get("html_instructions");
        }    Please try this because distance is jsonbobject type and you are trying to get in string. :) Hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

*First, you JSON is not syntactically correct but I assume it's due to way you took the snippet from the whole data, yet next time please either do that properly or strip the data to bare minimum need to reproduce the case (i.e. whatever is in "directions" or "duration" is irrelevant. You'd just remove it to have clearer picture next time.*

> This is what I have from java, which is not working

It is not working because you are trying read from `jsonObject` for most of the time, which is incorrect as it refers to root of your hierarchy. Additionally having variables named `jsonObject`, `jsonObject1` is asking for troubles. Sooner than later you make a typo. So to read what is in `html_instructions` field you need to do the following steps (pseudocode):

```
// get the root object
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

// get the routes (which is array)
JSONArray routes = jsonObject.optJSONArray("routes");

// get the 1st element of that array (which is object)
JSONObject singleRoute = routes.get(0);

// get route's legs array
JSONArray legs = singleRoute.get("legs")

// get its first element
JSONObject singleLeg = legs.get(0);

// get html_instructions
String html = singleLeg.get("html_instructions");
```

Answer (score 0):

> This will return you arraylist of route `ArrayList<LatLng> route`

```
public abstract class DirectionsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {
    private JSONObject jsonObject;

    public DirectionsAsync(JSONObject jResponse) {
        this.jsonObject = jResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONArray jRoutes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
            /** Traversing all routes */
            for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<>();
                /** Traversing all legs */
                for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {
                    JSONArray jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);
                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(list.get(l).latitude));
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(list.get(l).longitude));
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<>();
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(position);
            }
        }
        onGetRoute(points);
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }
        return poly;
    }

    public abstract void onGetRoute(ArrayList<LatLng> route);
}
```

> I think you want drow route so use below code to execute above class

```
new DirectionsAsync(jResponse) {//pass here json response got by google
                            @Override
                            public void onGetRoute(ArrayList<LatLng> route) {
                                PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                                polylineOptions.width(10).color(Color.BLUE).addAll(route);
                                if (polyLine != null) polyLine.remove();
                                polyLine = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                                polyLine.setPoints(route);
                            }
                        }.execute();
```

Comment: yes, i already having this code in my current project, working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You'r JSON is not correct, but if it was just a typing mistake.
use this.

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray routes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
if(routes!=bull && routes.lenght()>0);{
  JSONObject singleRoute = routes.get(0);
  JSONArray legs = singleRoute.get("legs")
  if(legs!=bull && legs.lenght()>0);{
     JSONObject singleLeg = legs.get(0);
     String html = singleLeg.get("html_instructions");
  }
```

}