# how to add polylines on map dynamically as my car moves near user by erasing previous line or update new line

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-polyline, google-directions-api

I am doing an app for car booking , here i need to add lines on map as and when car moves from driver location to user location . when i tried to do using recursion call to direction API so first it adds lines on map and will update nearly 6 times and suddenly crashing saying null pointer exception but why?

```
enter code here

        public void set_path_onmap( ) {

        LatLng driver_location = new LatLng(global_location.getLatitude(), global_location.getLongitude());
        Log.i("loc_drive", String.valueOf(driver_location));
        Log.i("loc_user", String.valueOf(user_location));
        String url = getDirectionsUrl(user_location, driver_location);

        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        downloadTask.execute(url);


}
public void timecalling() {

    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            set_path_onmap();
            timecalling();

        }
    }.start();

}
```

// here i am calling another method to add line on map which is working fine but when i do so recursivly it crashes after 6-7 call. Why ? or is their any other way to add lines dynamically as car moves near user i android

```
enter code here
```

//This is my call to add line on map
      //direction api start ***********************************************************************************************************

```
private class DownloadTask  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String data = "";

        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();


        parserTask.execute(result);


    }
}
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {


    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            ParserTask.DirectionsJSONParser parser = new ParserTask.DirectionsJSONParser();

            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {


      /*  List<LatLng> points = polyline.getPoints();
        points.add(newPoint);
        polyline.setPoints(points); */

         points = null;
        lineOptions = null;

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble((String) point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble((String) point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
                Log.i("pointsloop", String.valueOf(points));

            }

            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(8);
            lineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
            lineOptions.geodesic(true);

        }
        Log.i("pointsoutside", String.valueOf(points));
        Log.i("mapline", String.valueOf(lineOptions));
```

// Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);

```
    }

    private class DirectionsJSONParser {
        /**
         * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude
         */
        public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray jRoutes;
            JSONArray jLegs;
            JSONArray jSteps;
            try {
                jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
                    jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                    List path = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {
                        jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
                        for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                            String polyline = "";
                            polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                            List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);
                            for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
                                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                                hm.put("lat", Double.toString((list.get(l)).latitude));
                                hm.put("lng", Double.toString((list.get(l)).longitude));
                                path.add(hm);
                            }
                        }
                        routes.add(path);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return routes;
        }

        /**
         *      * Method to decode polyline points
         *      * Courtesy : https://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
         *      *
         */
        private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
            List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
            int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
            int lat = 0, lng = 0;
            while (index < len) {
                int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
                do {
                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                    shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lat += dlat;
                shift = 0;
                result = 0;
                do {
                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                    shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lng += dlng;
                LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                        (((double) lng / 1E5)));
                poly.add(p);
            }
            return poly;
        }

    }
}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    String mode = "mode=driving";
    String key="AIzaSyDz6HymXsuQbqGJkN70OVzNzNTr3pN9xBY";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor + "&" + mode+ "&" + key;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


    return url;
}

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        data = sb.toString();
        Log.d("downloadUrl", data.toString());
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

//***************DIRECTION API CLOSE *******************************************************************************************
```

Comment: would you mind to attach stacktrace?

Comment: Its calling properly and returning NULL points in JSON  after 6 or 7 time untill that it is working properly

Comment: by the way I see endless recursion here (inside onFinish method), which will in the end kill your thread's stack (it'll take a while, sure). would you mind to post this DownloadTask's class code?

Comment: E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: PolylineOptions cannot be null.
                                                                                            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.k.b(:com.google.android.gms

Comment: tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996662/polylineoptions-cannot-be-null

Comment: yes that avoid crash that i tried before also but not satisfying my requirement

Comment: Log the directions url and when it fails, manually enter the last/failing url into browser and look at results.  Your code as posted throws null point exception when there are no routes in the result.  (probably also want to remove your API key from post.)

Comment: yes no routes .but when i tried without api key but got an error saying Limit to API Call exceeded but when i run again works for up to 6 times then again same error